# Can't declare array from SQL string

Tags: php, sql, arrays

I have SQL string that suppose to be an array. I'm quite new in php and sql and can't figure out what to do next. Sorry for noob question.

I have query from sql, it's fine. Via mysql_fetch_array I've got cell I needed. It looks like:

> [{"id":"X","value":"Y"}{Same structure}{Same structure}]

As much as I understand this is short syntax array I can use. So I started from this:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
$extra_fields = $row['extra_fields']; 
}
```

For my understanding right now I declared array. But in the real world I didn't.

var_dump shows me a string. What should I do to declare proper array in cases like this?

Comment: You should not use mysql extension anymore cause it's deprecated and gets removed with one of the next PHP releases. Use PDO or mysqli instead.

Comment: try printing the array with print_r($resultvarofquery); and check whether you are getting the result as array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, your data is a *string representation* - and I assume that's JSON. You'll need to restore structure from JSON string. In PHP, there is [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) for that. For example,

```
//array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> string(1) "X" ["value"]=> string(1) "Y" } } 
var_dump(json_decode('[{"id":"X","value":"Y"}]', 1));
```

-so, you should do:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) 
{
   $extra_fields[] = json_decode($row['extra_fields'], 1); 
}
```

Hint: don't use *mysql* functions, they are deprecated. Use *mysqli* or *PDO* instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$data = array(); // create a variable to hold the information
while (($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) !== false){
  $data[] = $row; 
}

print_r($data); // print result
```